# How could I get a path to one project from another during runtime?

Tags: java

I have a project with 2 modules named
web-app and prebuildActions
and there is simple console application in prebuildActions.

the structure of folder is the next:

```
 |
 prj
   |
   project1
     -web-app
     -prebuild
```

I am running prebuild, but I dlike to get path to WEB-INF folder that located in the web-app

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

gave me a valid path to project but this was path to prebuild folder. Is it possible 
to get path to folder WEB-INF that located in other project folder grammatically without running this web-app ?  I am trying to organize pre-build generation of configs for this web-app

Perhaps -this is possible to go one level up executing project?
Something like `../../` ?

Comment: Is this in a specific IDE?

Comment: If this is only for your machine, have you considered environment variables? `System.getenv(String name)` You could define one variable for each project, containing their respective paths.

Comment: I am using IDEA, but is it depends from IDE?

Comment: I have try System.getenv("PATH") and I have got "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"  =(  Where I could define this variables with respective paths?

Comment: @curiousity, no, not like that. Define your own environment variables, then use those.
[1] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv(java.lang.String)
[2] http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables

Comment: Ok, thank you munyul, but also two new questions - first - could I change this variables automatic(the path contains version)? Secondly - could I do the same on windows platform?

Comment: @curiousity, yes. You can set/change the environment variables as you see fit. And this will work both in *nix and Windows.